# Differentiating $\left[\frac{\mathrm{d}^{n}}{\mathrm{d}x^{n}}(x^{2}-1)^{n}\right]^{2}$

Tags: derivatives

Given that $$\frac{\mathrm{d}^{2n}}{\mathrm{d}x^{2n}}(x^{2}-1)^{n} = (2n)!$$

How can we find $$\left[\frac{\mathrm{d}^{n}}{\mathrm{d}x^{n}}(x^{2}-1)^{n}\right]^{2}\quad ?$$

Comment: Did you try anything so far?

Comment: I don't think so, it is not true that $(n!)^2=(n^2)!$

Comment: Try with $n=1$ what happen?

Comment: @Chinny84 how does that relate to this question?

Comment: @user2850514 absolutely right!

Comment: Compare with [Rodrigues formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_formula) for Legendre polynomials.

Comment: @O.L. could you please explain us your idea?

Comment: @rlartiga If the asker wants an explicit sum expression, then the solution would be to expand using binomial formula, differentiate and simplify as below. But in case he would like to identify this sum with something known, I note that it is proportional to the squared $n$th degree Legendre polynomial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\left(\dfrac{d^n}{dx^n}(x^2-1)^n\right)^2$

$=\biggl(\dfrac{d^n}{dx^n}\sum\limits_{k=0}^nC_k^n(-1)^kx^{2n-2k}\biggr)^2$

$=\biggl(\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{(-1)^kn!(2n-2k)!x^{n-2k}}{k!(n-k)!(n-2k)!}\biggr)^2$

$=\biggl(\sum\limits_{k=0}^\left[\frac{n}{2}\right]\dfrac{(-1)^kn!(2n-2k)!x^{n-2k}}{k!(n-k)!(n-2k)!}\biggr)^2$

Comment: And where are you using the "hint"?

Comment: @rlartiga, the "hint" is obviously not useful.